# Split Objective-C String

Tags: objective-c

I have a string like this

```
NSString *string = @"feng2zhong3"
```

and I want to split this string to `feng2` and `zhong3`, how to do that?

Comment: Do you have a particular criterion for splitting strings or are you interested in splitting that string only?

Comment: r u looking for this string are general one your lookig

Comment: Not only one, it has lots of different string like this, so I need a general solution.

Comment: can u post some more strings....i ll find general one..

Comment: xiao3xin1 feng1kuang2 you3bang1zhu4 bu4tong2, chuang4yi4. It seems like these strings, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
NSString* feng = [string substringToIndex:4]
NSString* zhong = [string substringFromIndex:5]
```

EDIT:

Now that you have made it clear what your input data is like, one option is to use regexes to do the matches like this:

```
NSString* string = @"feng4shui5";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\D+\d+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
     NSRange matchRange = [match range];
     NSRange firstHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:1];
     NSRange secondHalfRange = [match rangeAtIndex:2];
     NSLog([userinput substringWithRange:matchRange]);
}
```

where string is the string that contains your input.

Comment: I guess it should be [a-z], not [a-b]

Comment: Regarding internationalization i guess something like `\D` would be better than `[a-z]`?

Comment: good idea, updated.  However, i was just assuming the examples provided cover all testcases.

Answer (score 0):

use substringFromIndex and substringToIndex methods

the below code is use full for you.it is working fine for your requirements

```
    NSMutableString *s = @"fig2sine3";
    NSCharacterSet *removeCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
    array=[s componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:removeCharSet];
```

nslog(@"the devided strings %@",array);

This is absolutely useful for your requirement.

Comment: This strips the trailing digits as well, i.e. "fig2sine3" becomes "fig","sine" instead of "fig2","sine3". Also just use `+decimalDigitCharacterSet`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `+[NSString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:options:range:]` with a `+[NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet]` and get the substrings via the resulting ranges.

Or you could use `NSScanner` by using:

```
NSCharacterSet *digitSet = [NSCharacterSet decimalDigitCharacterSet];
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:inputString];
```

... and successive calls of:

```
success = [scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:digitSet intoString:&namePart];
// ...
success = [scanner scanCharactersFromSet:digitSet intoString:&digitPart];
// ...
```